# Problem isolating the environment variable in a shell script

Tags: bash, environment-variables, shell-script, makefile

I’m a novice here but stackoverflow has helped me in the past.

I’m writing a bash shell script to generate a makefile (starting small).

```
echo "\
include \$(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make

APP_NAME = $PRODUCT_NAME
$PRODUCT_NAME_OBJC_FILES = source.m

include \$(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/application.make"\
> GNUmakefile
```

The environment variable set by the IDE where this is used is **$PRODUCT_NAME**. Now, bash obviously treats this script as referencing an environment variable **$PRODUCT_NAME_OBJC_FILES**. I see why, but I don’t know how to get around it. Any pointers?

**$PRODUCT_NAME** is evaluated as appropriate when the underscore isn’t following immediately afterwards, but the extra space messes things up down the line.

Comment: If you want to get serious about bash shell scripts, you might want to read the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.google.com/search?q=advanced+bash+scripting) (aka as "ABS").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `${PRODUCT_NAME}_OBJC_FILES`. The curly braces tell Bash explicitly where the variable name ends.